# Reveal animation not working as I'd like. Layout loading for split second then disappearing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrollreveal.js

So I have a reveal animation in my react app which uses ScrollReveal package and Im struggling to make it work properly.

The animation itself works great however I found that when I navigate through the app and come back to the home page where the layout is supposed to be revealed, the full layout shows up for a split second then disappears to begin the animation. I think its fair to want the animation to start right away and not have that gitter effect at the beggining.
I currently have it in a useEffect cuz I thought that would fix it however it didn't. It also tried useLayoutEffect and it doesn't work.

The code for the home page component that gets revealed:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ScrollReveal from "scrollreveal";
import {
    Title,
    HomeContainer,
    Subtitle,
    TitleButton,
  Hi,
  Name,
  ButtonContainer
} from "../../styles/Home-styles";

const Home = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    ScrollReveal().reveal('.title' , {duration: 500, origin:"top", distance: "0.5em", delay: 0 , easing: "ease-in-out"});
    ScrollReveal().reveal('.subtitle', {duration: 500, origin:"top", distance: "1em", delay: 300, easing: "ease-in-out"});
    ScrollReveal().reveal('.button', {duration: 500, delay: 1000, distance: '0px', opacity: 0, easing: "ease-in-out"})
  
  }, []);


    return (
        <HomeContainer>
            <Title className="title">
                <Hi>Hi, </Hi>
                <Name>I'm Saif.</Name>
            </Title>
            <Subtitle className="subtitle">This is a subtitle</Subtitle>
            <ButtonContainer className="button">
                <TitleButton to="/about">button</TitleButton>
            </ButtonContainer>
        </HomeContainer>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: "the full layout shows up for a split second then disappears" sounds a lot like you need to give the elements an initial style (display: none/opacity: 0/position offscreen, whatever is relevant)

Comment: @DBS but isnt that taken care of by the reveal animation? If i set the display to none in the css, the component will never be visible

Comment: I am not familiar with the reveal library, so I don't know, but that's normally what causes the issue you are describing in other libraries. (The "display none" comment was one of several options, the idea is to make sure the initial style matches the starting state of the animation)

Answer (score 0):

Your animation starts after a layout is rendered, because your useEffect hook is triggered after component is mounted. So first markup is rendered, only after that an animation takes place and force your elements to animate. Set initial CSS styles: hide elements behind the viewport using absolute positioning in CSS, use opacity: 0 and so on

Comment: but ok if i set my opacity 0 in the initial css styles, it stays 0 forever, do i need another transition inside the css itself?

Comment: I read the documentation. Never used this library before. So, you were right when you answered to @DBS in one of a previous comment. ScrollReveal takes care about an initial style of an element. You need to prevent flickering, that's because React applies an animation after an initial rendering, not before. And there is a separate page about this problem in a documentation scrollrevealjs.org/guide/user-experience.html As you use an NPM, you do not include a library link to a script tag in a head, a top part of this article is not applied to your code. Start read from "UTILITY CLASS" section

Comment: Adding a `load-hidden` class to the components that are revealed does not seem to do anything, i add the `visibility: hidden` and everything. Weird

Comment: Nvm, didnt need to add a class, I added the `visibility: hidden` to the component styles directly, thank you!

Comment: Maybe there is a requirement to add one more class: `html.sr .load-hidden`. But if directly set `visibility` to the component works, then OK

Comment: Thought i'd tell you that I found a way better library than scrollreveal and I've changed my code to work with it instead, its called Framer Motion and its made for react (scrollreveal was more for vanilla js) and has alot more features so check it out if you're interested